# What's meaning of the "run_once" in Caffe2's FillOp

Tags: caffe2

As in the
[Github link](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/tutorials/Basics.ipynb)
the "**run_once**" in the GaussianFill.

And where is the definition of the "**run_once**"?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Setting the parameter to 1 doesn't make it only run once...

Comment: Maybe it's some legacy argument from Caffe1?